# Plurals, possessive, and multiple nouns

Tags: compound-possessives

Are any of these two phrases appropriate, or are they both wrong?

> - tables two and three's information are more suited for
> - table two's and three's information is more suited for

Comment: Since *information* is singular, you can't say *"information are ..."* It's this mismatch of singular and plural which makes the first phrase sound incredibly awkward. Even with the verb fixed to *is*, it sounds much worse that "*units two and three's vehicles are ...*"